# Button click listener stop working after RxAndroid onError

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-binding

I am new with RxAndroid, I would like to understand why button clicks event stop working. I am using RxBinding and Retrofit 2 with Observables.

```
Subscription loginButtonSubscription = RxView.clicks(loginBtn)
        .throttleFirst(Constants.CLICK_THRESHOLD_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .flatMap(aVoid -> authApi.login(new LoginUserRequest(emailEditText.getText().toString(), passwordEditText.getText().toString())))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(verifyEmailResponse -> Log.i("TEST", "onNext: " + verifyEmailResponse.success),
                throwable -> handleError(throwable));
```

If I got an error (from login retrofit service) the method handleError is executed fine, but after that the click event is not fired anymore.

I am doing something wrong but I cant understand. There is better way to handle retrofit error?

Thanks

Comment: take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305865/onnext-onerror-callbacks-not-executing-on-second-subscribtion-android/40313481#40313481

Comment: I have checked but is not a solution.

Comment: It is. Because OnError calls OnComplete in source Observable so your subscription doesn't "works" any more. And PublishSubject wouldn't do it.

Comment: @AndroidRuntimeException have you found the solution yet? When I am trying to make many API calls (Retrofit + RxAndroid) at a time, sometimes my button can not be clicked anymore!

Answer (score 1):

Any error in an RxJava chain will cause both an `onError` and an `onCompleted` event, this is by design. Once the onCompleted event is called you are no longer subscribed hence the behaviour you are seeing.

In your case you want to keep the button working even if Retrofit returns an error which means it's worth you looking into the [`retry()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html) operator from RxJava.

Example but not guaranteed what you need:

```
Subscription loginButtonSubscription = RxView.clicks(loginBtn)
    .throttleFirst(Constants.CLICK_THRESHOLD_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .flatMap(aVoid -> authApi.login(new LoginUserRequest(emailEditText.getText().toString(), passwordEditText.getText().toString())))
    .doOnError(this::handleLoginError)
    .retry()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        verifyEmailResponse -> Log.i("TEST", "onNext: " + verifyEmailResponse.success),
        throwable -> handleError(throwable));
```